# toHaveBeenCalled is not working correctly with two Jasmine test cases on same spy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a spy object which I have used in two test cases. I am using toHaveBeenCalled method to check the spy method is called or not.

My code is working perfectly fine when used with one test case but when I use two test cases where I have used same spy, it gives incorrect result.

As per the code, it should call the spy in second call only for both the test cases but it's calling for the first call in second test case.

**My Source file**: `MyService.js`

```
...

this.setUserMethod1 = function () {
    if(this.loggedIn) {
        UtilService.User();
    }
}

this.setUserMethod2 = function () {
    if(this.loggedIn) {
        UtilService.User();
    }
}

...
```

**My Spec file**: `MyService.spec.js`

```
var UtilService = jasmine.createSpyObj('UtilService', ['User']);

UtilService.User.and.callFake(function () {
  return {
    setUser: function(){}
  };
});               

describe('MyService', function () {

 it('setUserMethod1  should do xyz', function () {
    MyService.loggedIn = false;
    MyService.setUserMethod1();
    expect(UtilService.User).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    MyService.loggedIn = true;
    MyService.setUserMethod1();
    expect(UtilService.User).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });

 it('setUserMethod2  should do pqr', function () {
    MyService.loggedIn = false;
    MyService.setUserMethod2();
    expect(UtilService.User).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    MyService.loggedIn = true;
    MyService.setUserMethod2();
    expect(UtilService.User).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });

});
```

It is giving following error:

```
debug.html:38 Expected spy UtilService.User not to have been called.
```

I think I am using same spy in both test cases and it's already called once which is causing the trouble.

May I please know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the root cause. I have used same spy in both test cases. Whenever second test case starts at that time spy call is already happened (in test case 1). So in second test case when I was expecting spy call not to happen, it was already happened (in test case 1). Hence test case was failing.

Solution is very simple we have to reset the spy call in beforeEach section.

```
....
....

beforeEach(function () {
  UtilService.User.calls.reset();
});

....
....
```